# plotting a vector in C++ with Cimg

Tags: c++, plot, cimg

As a part of a project I am working right now I need to plot a vector in a  style similar to MATLAB. After researching some of the possibilities I came across with CIMG which seemed easy enough to put into my program and just right for what I need. I am very new at C++ and never used Cimg before.

Following one of the examples provided in the guide I arrived at this program to plot the vector (in this case named ecg_r), my code looks like this:

```
// Read command line argument   cimg_usage("Simple plotter of ECG signal");
const char *const formula = cimg_option("-f", "x", "Formula to plot");
const float x0 = cimg_option("-x0", 0.0f, "Minimal X-value");
const float x1 = cimg_option("-x1", 20.0f, "Maximal X-value");
int sizeecg = ecg_r.size();
const int resolution = cimg_option("-r", sizeecg, "Plot resolution");
const unsigned int nresolution = resolution>1 ? resolution : sizeecg;
const unsigned int plot_type = cimg_option("-p", 1, "Plot type");
const unsigned int vertex_type = cimg_option("-v", 1, "Vertex type");

// Create plot data.
CImg<double> values(1, nresolution, 1, 1, 0);

const unsigned int r = nresolution - 1;

for (int i1 = 0; i1 < sizeecg; ++i1)
{
    double xtime = x0 + i1*(x1 - x0) / r;
    values(0, i1) = ecg_r.at(i1);
}  

// Display interactive plot window.
values.display_graph(formula, plot_type, vertex_type, "X-axis", x0, x1, "Y-axis");
```

the image I see in the display window created is exactly what I was expecting, but when I try to save the image in bmp using:

```
values.save_bmp("test.bmp");
```

the image is totally black, how can I save the image I am seeing in the display function? I spent yesterday afternoon going trough the documentation and couldn't find a clue.

Thank you in advance..

This is the MCVE of what I am trying to do, I want to be able to save in a bmp what I am seeing in the display window. Thank you

```
#include "CImg.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace cimg_library;

int main(int argc, char** const argv)
{
    cimg_usage("Simple plotter of mathematical formulas");
    const char *const formula = cimg_option("-f", "sin(x)", "Formula to    plot");
    const float x0 = cimg_option("-x0", -5.0f, "Minimal X-value");
    const float x1 = cimg_option("-x1", 5.0f, "Maximal X-value");
    const int resolution = cimg_option("-r", 5000, "Plot resolution");
    const unsigned int nresolution = resolution>1 ? resolution : 5000;
    const unsigned int plot_type = cimg_option("-p", 1, "Plot type");
    const unsigned int vertex_type = cimg_option("-v", 1, "Vertex type");

    // Create plot data.
    CImg<double> values(1, nresolution, 1, 1, 0);

    const unsigned int r = nresolution - 1;

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < resolution; ++i1)
    {
        double xtime = x0 + i1*(x1 - x0) / r;
        values(0, i1) = sin(xtime);
    }

    CImg<double> values2;
    values2 = values.display_graph(formula, plot_type, vertex_type, "X Axis", x0, x1, "Y Axis");
    values.normalize(0, 255);
    values.save_bmp("test.bmp");

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update Answer**

You were completely wrong, Mark! You can take a snapshot of the plot like this.

```
#include "CImg.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace cimg_library;

int main(int argc, char** const argv)
{
    cimg_usage("Simple plotter of mathematical formulas");
    const char *const formula = cimg_option("-f", "sin(x)", "Formula to    plot");
    const float x0 = cimg_option("-x0", -5.0f, "Minimal X-value");
    const float x1 = cimg_option("-x1", 5.0f, "Maximal X-value");
    const int resolution = cimg_option("-r", 5000, "Plot resolution");
    const unsigned int nresolution = resolution>1 ? resolution : 5000;
    const unsigned int plot_type = cimg_option("-p", 1, "Plot type");
    const unsigned int vertex_type = cimg_option("-v", 1, "Vertex type");

    // Create plot data.
    CImg<double> values(1, nresolution, 1, 1, 0);

    const unsigned int r = nresolution - 1;

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < resolution; ++i1)
    {
        double xtime = x0 + i1*(x1 - x0) / r;
        values(0, i1) = sin(xtime);
    }

    CImgDisplay disp;
    CImg<double> values2;
    values.display_graph(disp, plot_type, vertex_type, "X Axis", x0, x1, "Y Axis");
    disp.snapshot(values2);
    values2.save_bmp("result.bmp");
}
```

**Original Answer**

I am happy to be told I am completely wrong if anyone knows better, and shows us the way, but I don't believe that **CImg** will give you the plot as a bitmap file like you want.

So, I had a play with doing it using **gnuplot**. Your image looks like this on the screen:

[image]

So, as a rough approximation, if you make a few edits to your code like this:

```
#include "CImg.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace cimg_library;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** const argv)
{
    cimg_usage("Simple plotter of mathematical formulas");
    const char *const formula = cimg_option("-f", "sin(x)", "Formula to    plot");
    const float x0 = cimg_option("-x0", -5.0f, "Minimal X-value");
    const float x1 = cimg_option("-x1", 5.0f, "Maximal X-value");
    const int resolution = cimg_option("-r", 5000, "Plot resolution");
    const unsigned int nresolution = resolution>1 ? resolution : 5000;
    const unsigned int plot_type = cimg_option("-p", 1, "Plot type");
    const unsigned int vertex_type = cimg_option("-v", 1, "Vertex type");

    // Create plot data.
    CImg<double> values(1, nresolution, 1, 1, 0);

    const unsigned int r = nresolution - 1;

    ofstream data;
    data.open("plot.dat");

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < resolution; ++i1)
    {
        double xtime = x0 + i1*(x1 - x0) / r;
        values(0, i1) = sin(xtime);
        double x=x0 + i1*(x1-x0)/nresolution;
        data << x << " " << values(0,i1) << endl;
    }
    data.close();

    CImg<double> values2;
    values2 = values.display_graph(formula, plot_type, vertex_type, "X Axis", x0, x1, "Y Axis");
    cout << "set terminal png size 900,600 enhanced font \"Helvetica,20\"" << endl;
    cout << "set output 'out.png'" << endl;
    cout << "set xrange [" << x0 << ":" << x1 << "]" << endl;
    cout << "set grid" << endl;
    cout << "set ylabel 'Y Axis'" << endl;
    cout << "set xlabel 'X Axis'" << endl;
    cout << "plot \"plot.dat\" with linespoint lc 4" << endl;
}
```

and then run it like this:

```
./yourProgram | gnuplot
```

you will get this:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the response, unfortunately that is not the answer. when I do that the image it saves is an sizeecg by 1 pixel which i suspect is just the vector in image form. I want to save the image as I see it with the display_graph function

Comment: @DiegoFernandoPava Can you upload your output image and share it please?

Comment: @DiegoFernandoPava Can you provide all the code and data needed to make a MCVE - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thank you so much, yesterday I was finally able to do it by creating a function similar to display_graph but with an additional CImg<unsigned char> object as an input, and then storing the created image there.  That way I have control over the graph and could properly save it. I will however try the snapchot. I am pretty impressed with CImg, I wish it had better documentation.

Comment: I agree - it is a very powerful tool but there are very few decent examples of how to use it. Maybe a community will build up here on StackOverflow if enough people hear of it and try to use it... and ask questions just like you did. Anyway, good luck with your project!